# vue-router no procesa 404 en producción

Tags: vue.js, error404, vue-router

tengo el siguiente problema con vue-router. Cuando construyo mi proyecto de Vue y lo monto en un servidor local todas las rutas funcionan a la perfección incluyendo la página 404, cuando lo llevo a producción en github pages, todo va bien hasta que edito las rutas desde la url, y asi la ruta este correcta esta me manda a la pagina 404 de github pages en lugar de la mia.
(Si cambio la url en desarrollo, esta funciona perfectamente)

adjunto mi router.js

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router"
import HomeApp from "./components/HomeApp"
import AboutMe from "./components/AboutMe"
import Skills from "./components/Skills"
import MyProjects from "./components/MyProjects"
import PlayGround from "./components/PlayGround"
import ContactMe from "./components/ContactMe"
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound"
export const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes:
    [
        { path: '/', component: HomeApp, name:"home"},
        { path: '/about', component: AboutMe, name:"about"},
        { path: '/skills', component: Skills, name:"skills" },
        { path: '/projects', component: MyProjects, name:"projects"},
        { path: '/playground', component: PlayGround, name:"playground"},
        { path: '/contact', component: ContactMe, name:"contact"},
        { path: '/:pathName(.*)', component: NotFound, name:"not-found"},
    ]
})
```

el main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import {router} from './router'
import "bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

y una imagen del problema en gh pages

[image: error 404 de github pages]

Si les sirve de ayuda estoy usando webpack como empaquetador

Comment: ¿Tenés algún archivo llamado _404.html_?

Comment: no, tengo un componente llamado notFound.vue, en la carpeta de mis componentes

Answer (score 0):

Prueba en el app.vue a redirigir directamente a un componente de inicial como Home o asi:

> created() {
> this.$router.push("/HomeApp ");   },

y a mayores en el router.js
añade el componente Home tambien no solo como ruta por defecto:

> { path: '/HomeApp ', component: Home }.

A ver que tal